Плавная камера, разблокировка курсора на клавишу F
Нужно написать скрипт на LUA для Roblox studio, чтобы можно было разблокировать курсор на клавишу F.
То есть чтобы можно было водить курсором по экрану по нажатию на клавишу F, и когда снова нажму на F, то курсор заблокируется, и он был только для передвижения камеры с помощью компьютерной мыши. И хотел сделать плавный поворот камеры с помощью smoothness

Ваш вопрос похож на "Вопрос XY"

Самый простой способ это использование GUI элемента, добавь TextButton и поставь параметр Modal на true. Это костыль.Можно просто поменять тип камеры на Scriptable.(local script):

local Camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

Camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable



Добро пожаловать на ru.SO! Спасибо за ваше участие, но, к сожалению, ваш ответ не решает поставленную задачу. Вопрос был о том, как написать скрипт для разблокировки и блокировки курсора по нажатию клавиши "F", а также для плавного поворота камеры. В вашем ответе это не затронуто. Если сможете дополнить ваш ответ соответствующим кодом, это очень поможет [edit]
